# Android keyboard shows even after closing the application?

Tags: android, keyboard

I used these two line of code to make the keyboard appear:

```
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(v.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

But the keyboard appears even if I leave the application, so how do i it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put below code in onpause()  method in your class,

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
    INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

1) To show Keyboard

```
public void showSoftKeyboard() {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2) To hide keyboard

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```